# Replacing a pattern with another between first and second occurrence of a pattern in file

Tags: text-processing, ksh, aix

Want the comma's (,) replaced by the alphabet u between the first occurrence of y till the second occurrence of y. Given below is the sample input file.

```
100y00893225900,008932259,06,2013,NOKIA Q PHONE,TXS000000287356,PDF,Text,MEOB,1.4,00 00,DoD,07/07/2013,06/01/2013,06/30/2013,07/10/2024,trueyr=56734,d=199y
56734_199_0.pdf
100y00893225900,008932259,06,2013,SAMSUNG T PHONE,TXS000000287356,PDF,Text,MEOB,1.4,00 00,DoD,07/07/2013,06/01/2013,06/30/2013,07/10/2024,trueyr=56734,d=199y
56734_199_0.pdf      
100y00893225900,008932259,06,2013,APPLE S PHONE,TXS000000287356,PDF,Text,MEOB,1.4,00 00,DoD,07/07/2013,06/01/2013,06/30/2013,07/10/2024,trueyr=56734,d=199y
56734_199_0.pdf
~
~
~
```

Actually speaking each line has 3 "y" occurrences.

**Desired Output:**

```
100y00893225900u008932259u06u2013uNOKIA Q PHONEuTXS000000287356uPDFuTextuMEOBu1.4u00 00uDoDu07/07/2013u06/01/2013u06/30/2013u07/10/2024utrueyr=56734,d=199y
56734_199_0.pdf
100y00893225900u008932259u06u2013uSAMSUNG T PHONEuTXS000000287356uPDFuTextuMEOBu1.4u00 00uDoDu07/07/2013u06/01/2013u06/30/2013u07/10/2024utrueyr=56734,d=199y
56734_199_0.pdf
100y00893225900u008932259u06u2013uAPPLE S PHONEuTXS000000287356uPDFuTextuMEOBu1.4u00 00uDoDu07/07/2013u06/01/2013u06/30/2013u07/10/2024utrueyr=56734,d=199y
56734_199_0.pdf
~
~
~
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -Fy -v OFS=y '{gsub(",","u",$2); print}' file
```

Comment: :Thanks! Works Perfectly! Can please explain this?

Comment: This uses the character "y" as the field separator (`-Fy`). the text between the 1st and 2nd "y" is thus the 2nd field. Change the commas with the gsub command. Print out the modified line, using "y" as the *output* field separator (`-v OFS=y`)

Answer (score 0):

And here's a Perl one, only a little longer:

```
perl -Fy -ane 'do{$F[1]=~s/,/u/g; $,="y";} if /y/; print @F;' file
```